# Hibernate query insert

Tags: hibernate

could we realize an insert query with hibernate.
I read that must be a jdbc connection to the database if we want to insert into a table.
think you.

Comment: nhibernate is .NET; Hibernate and JDBC are Java.  Please clarify which one you mean.  You must create a connection to a database, regardless of platform.

Answer (score 2):

To do a raw SQL insert, you'll need indeed to use the underlying JDBC connection of the `Session` that you can get with `session.connection()`:

```
Connection conn = session.connection();
// create a java jdbc statement
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ...");
```